# Are arches allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, salafi

Daeesh recently [blew up](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/oct/05/isis-blows-up-another-monument-in-2000-year-old-city-of-palmyra?CMP=twt_gu) The Arch of Triumph in Palmyra.

It doesn't seem that the arches had any pagan content to them:

> “It is now wanton destruction … their acts of vengeance are no longer
>   ideologically driven because they are now blowing up buildings with no
>   religious meaning.”

Are arches allowed in Islam?

Comment: Well, whether arches are allowed or not, why would they be destroyed?? When Amr Ibn al 'Aas radiya Allahu 'anhu conquered Egypt, he didn't even harm or destroy the statues of the gods of the pharaohs. So why destroy a piece of architecture which doesn't resemble anything but an old civilization??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if one could find some references which are better then the fact, that the Sahaba -companions of the Prophet- (May Allah be pleased with them) and later many generations of Muslims lived and have been in what is now known as Egypt, Syria, Afghanistan, Iraq etc. and they didn't harm any of those historical monuments which where more or less attacked or destroyed by terrorist groups etc. which claim to be Muslims like Taliban or ISIL. But, do this people understand Islam better then those Sahaba? Are people there nowadays worshiping those places? To make their demolition necessary? ...

And on the other hand you may find that arches and pillars are typical parts of the architecture of mosques and "Islamic" buildings. Therefore it's hard to imagine that they are not allowed.

Maybe and this is an attempt -and my opinion only- to understand this (stupid) act they destroyed it because of the significance (Arch of Triumph) to show that the final triumph is theirs or in their strange understanding of Islam that they kept Allahs word higher than the word of pagans and destroyed it for the sake of Allah!